# Python: save only the newest login to file

Tags: python, list

I have this project where I need to process big access logs and get a list with the last login attempt for all users. While processing the logs I got to the point of having something like this:

```
[user1, <last login recorded>, <current login>]
[user2, <no last login recorded>, <current login>]
[user1, <last login recorded>, <current login>]
[user3, <last login recorded>, <current login>]
```

As you see, the same user has several logins recorded. And I would like to get only the newest login for the final list.

I'm using datetime objects for the login so comparing the current to the last is easy, but my question is: how can I temporarily save the current newest login and compare it to the next?

The simplified code looks like this

```
final_list = []
for login in log_file:
    login = login.split(';')
    last_login = get_last_login() #ldap search for the user last login
    if last_login:
        final_list.append([login[0], last_login, login[1]])
    else:
        final_list.append([login[0], 'no_last_login_recorded', login[1]])
```

So if I'm appending each login to the final_list[] is there a way to check if a user is already in there and compare the current login to the one in the list?

Comment: A little off topic but theres a command named `lastlog` on most Linux distros that prints the last login time for all the users.

Comment: @FlorinStingaciu Good to know, but I'm working with ldap access files here. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Just use a dictionary keyed by user - last write wins

Comment: @gkusner Could you provide an example on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @gkunser pointed out you can simply us a dictionary (`{}`) keyed to user something like this:

```
final_list = {}
for login in log_file:
    login = login.split(';')
    last_login = get_last_login();
    if last_login:
       final_list[login[0]] = (last_login, login[1]])
    ...
```

That way you will automatically overwrite the user login information

[This pseudo code used to suggest a Set which wasn't correct]

Comment: I'm trying to replicate this but I get "TypeError: 'set' object does not support item assignment"

Comment: Seeing @gkusner above I think you could user a dictionary (final_list = {}) instead of Set. I don't know why I thought you needed a set.Set here.

Comment: Sorry for my late reply, but after rethinking that method I realize a dictionary is exactly what I need.